# add an element to an empty vector in c++: why push.back works and [] not

Tags: c++, vector

Some years ago I had an introductory course to c++ at my university. However, I mainly used functional languages such as R or Matlab. Now I started again to learn c++. I was reading about vectors and run in the following:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <vector>

    int main()
    {      
      std::vector<int> test1;
  std::vector<int> test2(2);

  // works perfectly as expected:
  test2[0] = 1;
  test2[1] = 2;
  // this would give an error
  //test1[0] = 1;

  //instead I have to write
  test1.push_back(1);

      return 0;
    }
```

If I use default initialization for test1, why do I have to use puch_back? Wouldn't it be "smarter" to use the [] operator and automatically insert the element? Why is this forbidden in c++?

Comment: It is not "smarter".  "smart" containters will always come back to bite you and you'll spend a lot of time fighting them.  Different container classes do different things.  Use a std::map if you want to do what you are suggesting but be prepared for performance hits.

Comment: `push.back`, `push_back`, `puch_back` -- la-di-da, who cares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::vector`'s `operator[]` is designed to have the same semantics as it does for plain arrays. That is, it gives you access to an *existing* element with a certain index. An empty vector has no existing elements, so you have to add them in. `push_back` is one way of doing that. It has the effect of appending a new element to the back of a vector, increasing its number of elements by 1.

Comment: thanks for the quick anser. I was just wondering, what's the reason of doing so? For example in R, you can define an empty vector and initialize it with []. Of course it is not a proper programming language, that's the reason why I would like to understand what can go wrong

Comment: @user8 I extended my answer. Basically the vector's `[]` operator has the same semantics as for a plain array. And those semantics are "give me access to the element at position n". This comes from C, and it is simply a design decision. Some syntax for element access was required, and `[]` was chosen (probably taken from previous language, but I am not enough of a historian to know that.)